# eliminate index.php from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is what is in my .htaccess file right now.
Now I want to eliminate the index.php in my url. How do i do this?
I have tried several possibilities from this website but either i get a 500 internal error or nothing changes at all.

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder                                                 it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will rewrite index.php to index

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```